# Piping RETURN query to CREATE a new node (in-turn relationship)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I have a csv file with:

```
    name,city,country
    aa,london,UK
    bd,Berlin,Germany
    cr,helsinki,Finland
    fe,Washington,US
```

I am trying to import this *.csv and create a relationship. While the import part is successful, I am not able to assign a **special** relationship between a nodes

Eg:

```
(city)-[CAPITAL_OF]->(country) // This works (bw node to node)
```

But,

```
CREATE(state1:State{name=Washington, continent:North America)}
```

now, I need to create a new relationship between `(state1)-[IS_DIFFERENT_TO]->(?)` Where, the `?`is Washington DC city (the node previously created).

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DB.csv" AS csvline
MERGE(city:City{name:csvline.city})

MATCH (city:City{name:'Washington'})
RETURN city.name

CREATE(state1)-[:IS_DIFFERENT_TO]->(?)
```

I want to fill in the `?` with the retrieved node name

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you return is a name like string no node.
You should do something like

```
 Match()(where you look op state1)
 Match(city:City{name:'Washington'})
 CREATE(state1)-[:IS_DIFFERENT_TO]->(city)
 RETURN city.name
```

Or maybe i don't get it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I question whether the `IS_DIFFERENT_FROM` relationship is needed at all. Presumably, you do not have any nodes that have both `City` AND `State` labels. So, it should already be trivially easy to distinguish between a City and a State node, even if they have the same `name` property.

However, to answer the question you asked (as far as I could understand it): if the City and State nodes already exist, you just need to do something like this:

```
MATCH (city:City {name:'Washington'}), (state:State{name='Washington'})
CREATE (city)-[:IS_DIFFERENT_FROM]->(state);
```

1. I changed `IS_DIFFERENT_TO` to `IS_DIFFERENT_FROM`, to be more grammatical (to my North American ears).
2. Note that if there are multiple cities and/or states named 'Washington', this query will create a `:IS_DIFFERENT_FROM` relationship between all matching City/State pairs.

Comment: "different to" vs "different from" depends where you are ... British English (UK, Australia, etc) vs American ... and like our "lovely" inconsistent language ... not always black and white ;-)  ... http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/01/different-from-than-to/

Comment: @cybersam, Matt. Thanks for the clarification. While the above provided data was a toy example, the actual CSV file is too large for SO. My question was more on the lines of identifying a particular node - created by importing items from a CSV file- to be used for creating a relationship with a newly created node.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, or why you are specifically looking for "Washington" but based on your question this will do what you want (tested locally).

```
MERGE (washington:City {name:'Washington'})
WITH washington

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DB.csv" AS csvline
MERGE (city:City {name: csvline.city})
WITH city, washington

WHERE city.name <> washington.name
MERGE (city)-[:IS_DIFFERENT_TO]->(washington);
```